# Toggle the task in arraylist

Tags: java

I have a program that adds an activities, the activity can be complete or Incomplete. I've done everything except the method that toggles the task. It should check that there are tasks in the ArrayList (done), ask the user  for index   of  Task    in  the ArrayList   to  toggle (done) and change    the isCompleted into    what    it  is  not (not done). I shoel use getIsComplete and setIsComplete from another class. Help me please, how to do this method.

Here is what I have:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class ToDoListManager {

private static final int ADD_TASK = 1;
private static final int TOGGLE_TASK_COMPLETE = 2;
private static final int REMOVE_TASK = 3;
private static final int VIEW_TASKS = 4;
private static final int EXIT = 5;

private List<Task> tasks;
private Scanner input;

public ToDoListManager(){
    tasks = new ArrayList<Task>();
    input = new Scanner(System.in);
}

public void runToDoList(){
    int option = -1;
    while(option != EXIT){
        try{
            showMenu();
            option = input.nextInt();
            input.nextLine(); 
            switch(option){
            case ADD_TASK:
                addTask();
                break;
            //case TOGGLE_TASK_COMPLETE:
                //toggleTaskComplete();
                //break;
            case REMOVE_TASK:
                removeTask();
                break;
            case VIEW_TASKS:
                viewTasks();
                break;
            case EXIT:
                System.out.println("Program will exit");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Unrecognized command");
            }
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException ex){
            System.out.println("Please enter only numbers");
            input.nextLine(); // clear out bad data from stream
        }
    }
}

private void showMenu(){
    System.out.println(
            String.format("%d Add task", ADD_TASK));
    System.out.println(
            String.format("%d Toggle task", TOGGLE_TASK_COMPLETE));
    System.out.println(
            String.format("%d Remove task", REMOVE_TASK));
    System.out.println(
            String.format("%d View tasks", VIEW_TASKS));
    System.out.println(
            String.format("%d Exit program", EXIT));
}

private void addTask(){
    try{
        System.out.println("Please enter task title\n (Title cannon be empty, max 25 characters) ");
        String title = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter task priority (high, medium, low) ");
        String priority = input.nextLine();
        tasks.add(new Task(title, priority));
    }
    catch(ValidationException ex){
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}

//problem here
private void toggleTaskComplete(){
    try{
        if(tasks.size() <= 0){
            System.out.println("Nothing to toggle, tasks list is empty");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Enter index of task to toggle");
            int index = input.nextInt();
            input.nextLine();
            Task task1 = new Task();
            task1.getIsComplete();
            (getIsComplete)tasks.toggle(index);
        }
    }
    catch(InputMismatchException ex){
        System.out.println("Please enter only numbers");
    }
    catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException ex){
        System.out.println("Invalid index number");
    }   
}

private void removeTask(){
    try{
        if(tasks.size() <= 0){
            System.out.println("Nothing to remove, tasks list is empty");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Enter index of task to remove");
            int index = input.nextInt();
            input.nextLine();
            tasks.remove(index);
        }
    }
    catch(InputMismatchException ex){
        System.out.println("Please enter only numbers");
    }
    catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException ex){
        System.out.println("Invalid index number");
    }
}

private void viewTasks(){
    if(tasks.size() > 0){
        for(int index = 0; index < tasks.size(); index++){
            System.out.println(
                    String.format("Index: %d Person: %s", 
                            index, tasks.get(index)));
        }
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("No tasks to display");
    }
}
}
```

Class Task:

```
 public class Task {
 private String title;
 private String priority;
 private boolean isComplete;

 public Task(){
 title = "No title";
 priority = "No priority";
 }

 public Task(String title, String priority) throws ValidationException{
     setTitle(title);
     setPriority(priority);
 }

 public String getTitle(){
 return title;
 }


 public void setTitle(String title)throws ValidationException{
     if(title == null || title.trim().length() == 0){
            throw new ValidationException(
                    String.format("There was a problem adding a task:\n Title cannot be empty\n Please try again"));
        }
     else if(title.length() > 25){
            throw new ValidationException(
                    String.format("There was a problem adding a task:\n Title cannot exceed 25 characters\n Please try again"));
        }
 this.title = title.trim();
 }

 public String getPriority(){
 return priority;
 }

 // things to do here
 public void setPriority(String priority)throws ValidationException{
     if(priority.equals("high") || priority.equals("low") || priority.equals("medium")){
         this.priority = priority.trim();
     }
     else if(priority == null || priority.trim().length() == 0){
            throw new ValidationException(
                    String.format("There was a problem adding a task:\n Priority cannot be empty\n Please try again"));
        }
     else 
            throw new ValidationException(
                    String.format("There was a problem adding a task:\n Priority must be high, medium or low\n Please try again"));
        }

 public boolean getIsComplete(){
 return isComplete;
 }

 public void setIsComplete(boolean isComplete){
 this.isComplete = isComplete;
 }

 public String toString(){
        return String.format("%s (%s) %s", title, priority, isComplete);
    }
 }
```

Comment: What have you done? Where are you stuck? What issue are you having? Is there a question here, or is this a work request? If you have a specific issue that you are running into, we can help you, but we are not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: You need to be more explicit in your request. You are missing an exact question this is just a code dump with what you want. Flagging for closure unless improved.

Comment: A have a question about private void toggleTaskComplete() in the first code, becuse I don't know how to change the status of an activity from complete to "not complete".

Comment: @AnaF there is a function in your `Task` class `public void setIsComplete(boolean isComplete)`. So call that. `taskToChangeCompleteFlagOn.setIsComplete(!taskToChangeCompleteFlagOn.getIsComplete());`

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , and edit your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get the task at the index specified by the user
2. Get the current task status from that task
3. Set the task status to the opposite of what was found in step 2

Your `Task` class has the functions required for the above steps. You can get the current task status with `public boolean getIsComplete()` and then set the new task status with `public void setIsComplete(boolean isComplete)`.

I did it all in one line, but you can split it out if it makes it easier for you to understand. To do it in one line:

```
    tasks.get(index).setIsComplete(!tasks.get(index).getIsComplete());
```

Or to split it out:

```
    Task taskAtIndex = tasks.get(index);
    boolean taskAtIndexStatus = taskAtIndex.getIsComplete();
    taskAtIndex.setIsComplete(!taskAtIndexStatus);
    tasks.add(index, taskAtIndex);
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Now examle of my outout is "Index: 0 Person: hw (low) true" I have 1 one question, how can I do to return "is complete" is spite of "true" or "is not complete" is spite of "false"? And thank you very much!!!

Comment: @AnaF You can use a ternary operator. For example, to output this message: `System.out.println(taskAtIndex.getIsComplete() ? "Task is complete" : "Task is not complete");`. If you want to return the value, do the same thing but with a return statement. `return taskAtIndex.getIsComplete() ? "Task is complete" : "Task is not complete"`. Although, your `toggleTaskComplete` function does not return anything (it's return type is `void`), so you would need to change that if you wish to return something.